# Cannot place Swift assertions inside init() before call to super.init()

Tags: swift, assert, init, swift2

I would like to use assertions inside `init()` before it calls `super.init()`. They are meant to check certain invariant conditions when calculating local properties.

However, if I try place such assertions I get this error message:

> 'self' used before super.init call

I assume this is because assert prints a description of the object and hence uses `self`, which at this point is not yet fully initialized. Is there anything I can do about this (i.e. calculate local properties before call to `super.init()` and place assertions there).

**UPDATE** Here is an concise example:

```
class Test: NSObject {
    let x: Int

    override init() {
        x = 1
        assert(x == 1) // causes error
        super.init()
        assert(x == 1) // no error
    }
}
```

Comment: Show some code what you're trying to do ... In the meanwhile, read [Swift Asserts](http://blog.krzyzanowskim.com/2015/03/09/swift-asserts-the-missing-manual/) as well to know all alternatives/ways ...

Comment: @robertvojta I've added an example (with trivial initialization logic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that `assert`has to read the value of the property `x`.
Although you can omit `self` as a convenience syntax `assert` uses the implicit setter of the property and has to call `self.x == 1`.

That's what the error message says.

You can use temporary local variables to calculate what you need but you cannot use instance variables before calling `super.init()`.

Alternatively use a `struct` or `protocol` type which doesn't require to call `super.init()`